# Ruby on Rails - Showing different code (button) every 2 user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

I'm running `Rails 4.2.2` in my application. There is some part  of my website that I would like to display different code/element **every 2 user**.

I know I can achieve this with `split gem` but its not a A/B testing and I don't want to make it complicated.

So basically it works like this:

**Visit 1:**
`<button>Login</button>`

**Visit 2**
`<h1>Welcome to our website</h1>`

**Visit 3:**
`<button>Login</button>`

**Visit 4**
`<h1>Welcome to our website</h1>`

*etc*

Is it any way I can achieve this without 'split gem' or some sort of `A/B testing gem`.

Comment: Rather than over-complicating it, why not just use `rand()`?

Comment: What is your reason for doing this without tracking it?

Comment: You can use it for different reasons, one of the cases Im going to use it for showing different texts (don't need tracking) and/or show different ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple **`rand`** method

```
<% if rand(2).zero? %>
  <button>Login</button>
<% else %>
  <h1>Welcome to our website</h1> 
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

If you have more than 2 elements then its better to go for hash or case statement

Create a helper method

```
def conditional_element(option)
  hash = {
    0 => "<button>Login</button>",
    1 => "<h1>Welcome to our website</h1>",
    2 => "Some other element"
  }
  hash[option]
end
```

**OR**

```
def conditional_element(option)
  case option
  when 0
    "<button>Login</button>"
  when 1
    "<h1>Welcome to our website</h1>"
  when 2
    "Some other element"
  end
end
```

And use it in view

```
<%= conditional_element(rand(3)) %>
```

NOTE: You need to change the number in `rand` as per your number of elements

Comment: Thanks @Deepak , It does work (sort of). It does change them but its not exactly for each visit/refresh. Sometimes I need to refresh/visit the page twice or 3 times before it change back.

Comment: yes, You cant be sure that it will switch exactly after each visit as its random. But the probability is 50-50

Comment: So if you aren't concerned about the switch for each visit you can use it

Comment: Okei great. Thanks @Deepak One last thing. How can I add a third element as well? And is it a documentation I can read how it does work?

Comment: If you have more than 2 elements I will say go for `hash ` or `case` statement

Comment: You have been a huge help, but could you please also add `hash` or `case` as part of the answer as well? Thanks a bunch

Comment: @user6589814 This solution will show a **random** value, because... shockingly... it is based on the use of `rand`. I'm sure you can work out yourself how to write it as a `case` statement - the basic [syntax](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) is pretty simple.

Comment: While the original question you asked is indeed *possible*, it's a bad idea to implement - as it adds much more complication, with no real benefit.

Comment: I have added methods with `case` statement and `hash` give it a try